# Parsing a div with a "class" attribute

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Using the BeautifulSoup module in Python, I'm trying to parse this webpage below.

```
<div class="span-body"><div class="timestamp updated" title="2016-05-08T1231Z">May 8, 12:31 PM EDT</div></div>
```

I'm trying to get the script below to return `2016-05-08T1231Z`, which is found in the second div with the `timestamp updated` class.

```
with open("index.html", 'rb') as source_file:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_file.read()) # Read the source file and get BeautifulSoup to work with it.
    div_1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "span-body"}).contents[0] # Parse the first div.
    div_2 = div_1("div", {"class": "timestamp updated"}) # Parse the second div.
    print div_2
```

`div_1` returns what I wanted to return (the second div), but `div_2` isn't, instead it's only giving me an empty list in return.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options, all of which you should just drop `contents[0]`:

```
div_1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "span-body"}) # Parse the first div.
div_2 = div_1("div", {"class": "timestamp updated"})
```

This will return a list with one element in it:

```
[<div class="timestamp updated" title="2016-05-08T1231Z">May 8, 12:31 PM EDT</div>]
```

Just use `find()`:

```
div_1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "span-body"})
div_2 = div_1.find("div", {'class': 'timestamp updated'})
print(div_2)
```

Result:

```
<div class="timestamp updated" title="2016-05-08T1231Z">May 8, 12:31 PM EDT</div>
```

If you don't need the intermediate `div_1` why not just go straight to `div_2`?

```
div_2 = soup.find("div", {'class': 'timestamp updated'})
```

Edit from comment: To get the value of the title attribute you can index it like this:

```
div_2['title']
```

Comment: I cleaned it up now with your method to just go straight to `div_2` and it works better, but from there I was trying to ask about taking that and returning the contents of the `title` attribute. How do I do that from here?

Comment: You can simply index it. `print(div_2['title'])`

Comment: [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) doesn't return a list, it's the same as calling `find_all(limit=1)`

Comment: Did you even try running the code? I didn't say `find` returned a list and the answer is in the link you provided...

Comment: You don't need to have an attitude. At the top of your answer you do indeed say that it will return a list with one element.

Comment: Well, not exactly the same. `find_all(limit=1)` returns a list with one element. `find()` returns a string.

Comment: Exactly, calling a tag is the same as calling `find_all`. So, it's a list with one element in it. Well... technically it's a `ResultSet` object.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I didn't realize it returns a list when called that way. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

To find what you want from `div_1` you need to use the find function again, also you can get rid of the `contents[0]` as find doesn't return a list.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_file.read()) # Read the source file and get BeautifulSoup to work with it.
div_1 = soup.find("div", {"class": "span-body"}) # Parse the first div.
div_2 = div_1.find("div", {"class": "timestamp updated"}) # Parse the second div.
print div_2
```